# Iframe's width should expand max to the width of its container

Tags: css

I have a DIV whose width is defined in a CSS class. Inside this DIV, i am rendering the Facebook's LIKE button, but since the LIKE button gets rendered inside an IFRAME, whenever the page is browsed from a machine which does not have access to FACEBOOK,  "**The Page cannot be displayed**" is seen in place of the LIKE  button.
  The Problem is seen when the user does have access to FACEBOOK. Here, the IFRAME does not respect the width of its container and it expands to the width set for the IFRAME by inline styling.

Here is what I have in CSS :

```
.socialLinks {  /* This CSS is applied to the container DIV */
width: 97px;
float: right;
text-align: center;
}
```

Any pointers ?

**UPDATE :**

Got it !.

Adding

```
overflow:hidden;
```

to the DIV class solves it !

Thanks anyway !

Comment: Make it in answer section

Comment: Not allowed brother ! says that i have to wait for 7 hours to do so!